# How to replace multiple parent nodes with a single parent node using LINQ to Xml?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm using the following code to generate XML from list,

```
var xEle = new XElement("DataDictionary",
               from emp in factDetails
               select new XElement(emp.ElementPrefix.Contains("dei") ? "filingInfo" : "TaggableContent",
                          new XElement(p.GetParameterType(emp.ElementType,emp.ElementPrefix),
                              new XElement("xbrlElementInfo",
                                  new XAttribute("name", emp.ElementName),
                                  new XElement("ContentValue", emp.FactValue)
 ))));



//Function to Get the Element Name.
public string GetParameterType(string p, string prefix)
{
    if (prefix.Contains("dei"))
    {
        return "filingItem";
    }
    else
    {
        if (p.Contains("TABLE"))
            return "cell";
        else
        {
            return "paragraph";
        }
    }
}
```

Present Output, Since I'm using ternary operation based on a column value(**emp.ElementPrefix**), Parent nodes are getting generated for each Xelement, instead it should create one parent node instead of multiple parent nodes :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataDictionary>
  <filingInfo>
    <filingItem>
      <xbrlElementInfo name="DocumentType">
        <ContentValue>485BPOS</ContentValue>
      </xbrlElementInfo>
    </filingItem>
  </filingInfo>
  <filingInfo>
    <filingItem>
      <xbrlElementInfo name="DocumentPeriodEndDate">
        <ContentValue>2013-06-30</ContentValue>
      </xbrlElementInfo>
    </filingItem>
  </filingInfo>
    <TaggableContent>
    <cell>
      <xbrlElementInfo name="AcquiredFundFeesAndExpensesOverAssets">
        <ContentValue>0.0001</ContentValue>
      </xbrlElementInfo>
    </cell>
  </TaggableContent>
  <TaggableContent>
    <cell>
      <xbrlElementInfo name="AcquiredFundFeesAndExpensesOverAssets">
        <ContentValue>0.0001</ContentValue>
      </xbrlElementInfo>
    </cell>
  </TaggableContent>
</DataDictionary>
```

Output Expected : (`<filingInfo> & <TaggableContent>` should be the parent nodes instead of creating child nodes for each element) as shown below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataDictionary>
  <filingInfo>
    <filingItem>
      <xbrlElementInfo name="DocumentType">
        <ContentValue>485BPOS</ContentValue>
      </xbrlElementInfo>
    </filingItem>
    <filingItem>
      <xbrlElementInfo name="DocumentPeriodEndDate">
        <ContentValue>2013-06-30</ContentValue>
      </xbrlElementInfo>
    </filingItem>
  </filingInfo>
    <TaggableContent>
    <cell>
      <xbrlElementInfo name="AcquiredFundFeesAndExpensesOverAssets">
        <ContentValue>0.0001</ContentValue>
      </xbrlElementInfo>
    </cell>      
    <cell>
      <xbrlElementInfo name="AcquiredFundFeesAndExpensesOverAssets">
        <ContentValue>0.0001</ContentValue>
      </xbrlElementInfo>
    </cell>
  </TaggableContent>
</DataDictionary>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating whole xml hierarchy for each item of ienumerable,
in expected output there are grouped values.

There are two ways to make it:

Two separate queries:

```
var fillingIngo = 
    from emp in factDetails
    where emp.ElementPrefix.Contains("dei")
    select new XElement(p.GetParameterType(emp.ElementType,emp.ElementPrefix),
                new XElement("xbrlElementInfo",
                    new XAttribute("name", emp.ElementName),
                    new XElement("ContentValue", emp.FactValue)));

var taggableContent = 
    from emp in factDetails
    where !emp.ElementPrefix.Contains("dei")
    select new XElement(p.GetParameterType(emp.ElementType,emp.ElementPrefix),
            new XElement("xbrlElementInfo",
                new XAttribute("name", emp.ElementName),
                new XElement("ContentValue", emp.FactValue)));



var result = new XElement(
    "DataDictionary",
    new[]
        {
            new XElement("filingInfo", fillingIngo), 
            new XElement("TaggableContent", taggableContent)
        });
```

Or use group by:

```
var xEle = new XElement("DataDictionary",
    from fd in factDetails
    group fd by fd.ElementPrefix.Contains("dei") into gr
    select new XElement(gr.Key ? "filingInfo" : "TaggableContent",
                from emp in gr
                select new XElement(p.GetParameterType(emp.ElementType,emp.ElementPrefix),
                    new XElement("xbrlElementInfo",
                        new XAttribute("name", emp.ElementName),
                        new XElement("ContentValue", emp.FactValue)))));
```

Comment: Thanks pilOt :) you rock!